# Got READU unit:100 error when read fits image using IDL

Tags: idl

I have a fits image need to be process, which has the size of 4.9G. I use three function to open this image, which are "readfits", "mrdfits" and "fits_read". But these three function all gave me the following error message. The error message is:

```
READU: Error encountered reading from file. Unit: 100
         File: /Users/lpr/Data/CANDELS_image.fits
```

I hope someone know the reason that I got this error. Or, help me fix this problem.

I have done all the search I can, and still get no solution. There is a [site](http://idlcoyote.com/comp.lang.idl-pvwave/index.php?t=msg&goto=87526&&srch=READU%3A+Error+encountered+reading+from+file.#msg_87526) , very similar with my question. The difference is I met this error on MAC, and this user met on Windows. And this user also got no reply.

I also try to fix this problem by modifying READU source code, but it told me "READU" is an internal function, so I cannot do any changes to it.

The IDL version I used is IDL 7.1. If I didn't say clearly, please leave a comment below.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Sorry for my bad English, I edited the question. I want to fix this problem, because I need to process this image (its format is fits).